# Where are network namespaces in lxc / lxd?

Tags: networking, virtualization, lxc

I am trying to [understand namespaces](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/) in the context of `lxd` / `lxc`.

I have two containers which respective `eth0` is bridged to `br1` and `br2` on the host. This is done via a Virtual Ethernet interfaces

```
root@srv:~# ip link
(...)

5: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether fe:f0:ca:e8:c4:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether fe:45:66:a8:37:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: vethHRMPOM@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:f0:ca:e8:c4:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
27: vethNTG58H@if26: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br2 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:45:66:a8:37:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

I wonder where the other side of, say, `vethHRMPOM@if10` is?

`ip netns list` is empty.

`/var/run/netns` does not exist (this is an Ubuntu 15.10)

`ip netns list-id` shows

```
nsid 0 
nsid 1
```

which seem to correspond to the last element in the `ip list` above. How can I get more information about these `nsid 0` an `1` since all commands refer to a namespace by name (and not ID)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default LXC doesn't register the network namespaces with iproute2 utils, but you can register them manually:

```
root@host:~# lxc-info -n testlxc
Name:           testlxc
State:          RUNNING
PID:            8888
<snip>
root@host:~# mkdir -p /var/run/netns/
root@host:~# ln -s /proc/8888/ns/net /var/run/netns/testlxc
```

After the netns is registered, it's easy to answer the question:

```
root@host:~# ip netns list
testlxc (id: 0)
root@host:~# ip addr show | grep -A2 -B1 "link-netnsid 0"
15: veth9ICKL6@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:b2:e0:99:81:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::fcb2:e0ff:fe99:8153/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder where the other side of, say, `vethHRMPOM@if10` is?

While I don't know how to directly map host veth devices to LXC veth device, I know how to do the inverse:

```
root@server:~# lxc-ls
bugzilla4
root@server:~# lxc-info -n bugzilla4 -p
PID:            7072
root@server:~# mkdir -p /var/run/netns/
root@server:~# ln -sf /proc/7072/ns/net /var/run/netns/bugzilla4
root@server:~# ip netns list
bugzilla4
root@server:~# ip netns exec bugzilla4 ethtool -S eth0
NIC statistics:
     peer_ifindex: 41
root@server:~# ip link show | grep '^41:'
41: vXsomething: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

If `ethtool` is not available on the guest I think you can just get the guest `ifindex` and increment with one to get the host `ifindex` (40 -> 41):

```
root@server:~# ip netns exec bugzilla4 ip link show eth0
40: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

To answer your original question: you can write a script which will go over each LXC, get the host veth device, and stop if it's the one you're interested in (`vethHRMPOM@if10`).

A better solution in my opinion would be to name your veth devices properly. Example:

```
lxc.network.veth.pair = vXbugzilla4
```

The veth device is called `vXbugzilla4` on the host:

```
root@server:~# ip link show vXbugzilla4
41: vXbugzilla4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```